# Setting OnClickListener on SnackBar not setAction()?

Tags: java, android, android-snackbar

I am trying to find out how can I get snackbar to to have an onClickListener. here is a simple code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            snackbar.make(v, "This is a snackBar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
                    .show();
        }
    });
```

I know about setAction() but I want snackBar itself be my click button. I know new androidx support library has changed so many of the solutions I found online are not useful anymore.

EDIT: Why this piece of code does not work with it?

```
View view = snackbar.getView();
    TextView text = view.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text);
    text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          
        }
    });
```

I Have fixed my problem by coding the snackbar object inside the onClickListner() instead of introduced as a field object. Apparently my main issue was related to this chnage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by snackbar you mean [android.support.design.widget.Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar), then you might want to use the [addCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BaseTransientBottomBar#addCallback(android.support.design.widget.BaseTransientBottomBar.BaseCallback%3CB%3E)) method, to be notified on dismissal.

```
snackbar.addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
  @Override
  public void onDismissed(final Snackbar snackbar, final int event) {
    ...
  }
});
```

Compare the `event` parameter with the [static constants](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/snackbar/Snackbar.Callback#constants_1) to understand how it was dismissed.

Comment: I have edited the text. see if you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Rklearner I do not know why it doesn't work, however I would not do it like that, it's just messy.

Comment: @Rklearner have you tried my proposed solution?

Comment: callback() works fine but I need to make it go away either by clicking on it or swipe it away.

Comment: @Rklearner the onDismissed method is called when the Snackbar goes away, that's why I do not understand what goes wrong. I mean, onDismissed is called when you swipe the Snackbar

Comment: @Rklearner see the DISMISS_EVENT_SWIPE event type, or DISMISS_EVENT_ACTION.